# Adding Localized Watermarks and Tool-tips to MVC Views

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm fairly new to MVC 4 and I'm trying to localize the Tooltip and Watermarks for textbox input fields. The MS documentation for the `DisplayAttribute` would suggest that I do this as follows in my **Model** class:

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), Name = "ApplicantGivenNameLabel", Description = "ApplicantGivenNameDescription", Prompt = "ApplicantGivenNameWatermark")]
public string GivenName { get; set; }
```

This does not appear to work for the browsers I've tested. Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

For context, the field looks as follows in the **View**:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.GivenName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GivenName, new { required = string.Empty })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.GivenName)
```

Comment: Not sure if this has changed in mvc 4 but asp.net mvc doesn't support all the properties in DisplayAttribute. For watermarks you can handle it on the client using jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out there are at least two seperate solutions for the question I presented.

### Adding Tooltips To MVC Models

In this case I created and Extension Method to extend the built-in HtmlHelper.

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxWithTooltipFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);

    if (htmlAttributes == null)
    {
        htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object> { { TITLE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, metaData.Description } };
    }
    else
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(metaData.Description) && !htmlAttributes.Keys.Contains(TITLE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME))
            htmlAttributes.Add(TITLE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, metaData.Description);
    }

    return helper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
}
```

This is what the **Model** may look like

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), Name = "FirstNameLabel", Description = "FirstNameTooltip")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

This is how you would use this in **Razor**

```
@Html.TextBoxWithTooltipFor(m => m.FirstName, new { type = "text", required = string.Empty })
```

### Adding Watermarks

I wasn't able to leverage the **Model** attributes in any elegant way so I opted for a **JQuery** solution. Here is the **JQuery**, which I altered from some other samples of similar patterns

```
$.fn.Watermark = function (text) {
    return this.each(
        function () {
            //This ensures Diacritic characters are encoded correctly
            text = $('<span>' + text + '</span>').text(); 

            var input = $(this);
            map[map.length] = { text: text, obj: input };
            function clearMessage() {
                if (input.val() == text)
                    input.val("");
                input.removeClass("watermark");
            }

            function insertMessage() {
                if (input.val().length == 0 || input.val() == text) {
                    input.val(text);
                    input.addClass("watermark");
                } else
                    input.removeClass("watermark")
            }

            input.focus(clearMessage);
            input.blur(insertMessage);
            input.change(insertMessage);

            insertMessage();
        }
    );
};
```

Here is my **CSS** to style the **watermark**

```
fieldset input[type="tel"].watermark, 
fieldset input[type="email"].watermark, 
fieldset input[type="text"].watermark, 
fieldset input[type="password"].watermark {
    color : #9B9B9B; 
    font-size: 0.7em;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

This is how you would use this in **Razor**

```
$("#FirstName").Watermark("@Resources.FirstNameWatermark");
```

***Note**: Make sure you clear the watermarks before submitting your form, this can be done with a variation of the **JQuery** I supplied above and used as follows:*

```
$('#Application').submit(function () {
    $.Watermark.RemoveAll();
    return true;
});
```